# Null Pointer Exception in Android Code

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, chat

Please somebody can tell me where i can find Null Pointer Exception in this code.. it will be thankful.

This is a chat code for group messaging and i am trying to run on my emaluator but it is showing error as of null pointer exception.

```
package edu.buffalo.cse.cse486586.groupmessenger;

public class GroupMessengerActivity extends Activity {

private int emulator_instance;
final String localHost="127.0.0.1";
boolean test2=false;
final int sequencerNumber = 5554;
static int globalClock,localClock,sequenceNumberLocalApp;
static int avd0LocalClock,avd1LocalClock,avd2LocalClock;
Map<Long,String> holdbackQueue;
Map<Long,Integer> sequenceQueue;
Map<String,String> sequenceOrderingQueue;
ContentValues cv_pushToContentProvider;
private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
private Uri mUri;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_messenger);
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String portStr = tel.getLine1Number().substring(tel.getLine1Number().length());
    emulator_instance=Integer.parseInt(portStr);
    mUri = buildUri("content", "edu.buffalo.cse.cse486586.groupmessenger.provider");
    mContentResolver=getContentResolver();
    createServer();
    holdbackQueue = new HashMap<Long, String>();
    sequenceQueue = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
    if(emulator_instance == sequencerNumber)
    {
        sequenceOrderingQueue = new HashMap<String,String>();   
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(
            new OnPTestClickListener(tv, getContentResolver()));
        }
private Uri buildUri(String scheme, String authority) {
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
    uriBuilder.authority(authority);
    uriBuilder.scheme(scheme);
    return uriBuilder.build();
}
private void createServer() 
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(10000);
                while(true)
                {
                    Socket ss=s.accept();
                    String msg_ServerSide=null;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));
                    msg_ServerSide=br.readLine();
                    //System.out.println(msg_ServerSide);
                    String[] message=msg_ServerSide.split(",");
                    //System.out.println(message.length);
                    if(message.length > 3)
                    {
                        testCaseMultiCastMessage();//testCase2
                    }
                    if(message[0].equals("sequenceMessage"))
                    {
                        if(localClock+1 == Integer.parseInt(message[2]))
                        {
                            if(sequenceQueue.containsKey(Long.parseLong(message[1])))
                            {
                                String upMesg=holdbackQueue.get(Long.parseLong(message[1]));
                                new displayMessage().execute(upMesg);
                                localClock++;
                                holdbackQueue.remove(Long.parseLong(message[1]));
                                sequenceQueue.remove(Long.parseLong(message[1]));
                                checkSQ((localClock+1));
                            }
                            else if(holdbackQueue.containsKey(Long.parseLong(message[1])))
                            {
                                String upMesg=holdbackQueue.get(Long.parseLong(message[1]));
                                new displayMessage().execute(upMesg);
                                localClock++;
                                checkSQ(localClock+1);
                                holdbackQueue.remove(Long.parseLong(message[1]));
                            }
                            else if(!sequenceQueue.containsKey(Long.parseLong(message[1])))
                            {
                            sequenceQueue.put(Long.parseLong(message[1]), Integer.parseInt(message[2]));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(!sequenceQueue.containsKey(Long.parseLong(message[1])))
                            {
                            sequenceQueue.put(Long.parseLong(message[1]), Integer.parseInt(message[2]));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {                               
                        if(emulator_instance == sequencerNumber)
                        {
                            //System.out.println(message[0]);
                            String [] locArr=message[0].split(":");
                            String localClockCheck=locArr[0];
                            int localMessageClock=Integer.parseInt(locArr[1]);
                            if(localClockCheck.equals("avd0"))
                            {
                                if((avd0LocalClock)==localMessageClock)
                                {
                                    multiCastSequence(message[1]);
                                    avd0LocalClock++;
                                    orderingQueueCheck(0);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sequenceOrderingQueue.put(message[0], message[1]);
                                }
                            }
                            else if(localClockCheck.equals("avd1"))
                            {
                                if((avd1LocalClock)==localMessageClock)
                                {
                                    multiCastSequence(message[1]);
                                    avd1LocalClock++;
                                    orderingQueueCheck(1);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sequenceOrderingQueue.put(message[0], message[1]);
                                }
                            }
                            else if(localClockCheck.equals("avd2"))
                            {
                                if((avd2LocalClock)==localMessageClock)
                                {
                                    multiCastSequence(message[1]);
                                    avd2LocalClock++;
                                    orderingQueueCheck(2);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sequenceOrderingQueue.put(message[0], message[1]);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        if(!holdbackQueue.containsKey(Long.parseLong(message[1])))
                        {
                        holdbackQueue.put(Long.parseLong(message[1]), message[0]);
                        checkSQ(localClock+1);
                        }
                        //System.out.println(holdbackQueue+" "+sequenceQueue+" "+sequenceOrderingQueue);
                        if(holdbackQueue!=null && sequenceQueue!=null && sequenceOrderingQueue!=null)
                        {
                            //System.out.println(holdbackQueue.size()+" "+sequenceQueue.size()+" "+sequenceOrderingQueue.size());
                        }
                        br.close();
                        ss.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void orderingQueueCheck(int ii) {
            Set<String> checkString=sequenceOrderingQueue.keySet();
            Iterator<String> i=checkString.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext())
            {
                String shouldIMultiCastMessage=(String)i.next();
                String [] here=shouldIMultiCastMessage.split(":");
                int clockVal=Integer.parseInt(here[1]);
                if(ii == 0)
                {
                    if((avd0LocalClock) == clockVal)
                    {
                        multiCastSequence(sequenceOrderingQueue.get(shouldIMultiCastMessage));
                        avd0LocalClock++;
                        sequenceOrderingQueue.remove(shouldIMultiCastMessage);
                        orderingQueueCheck(0);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(ii == 1)
                {
                    if((avd1LocalClock) == clockVal)
                    {
                        multiCastSequence(sequenceOrderingQueue.get(shouldIMultiCastMessage));
                        avd1LocalClock++;
                        sequenceOrderingQueue.remove(shouldIMultiCastMessage);
                        orderingQueueCheck(1);
                        break;
                    }                       
                }
                else if(ii == 2)
                {
                    if((avd2LocalClock) == clockVal)
                    {
                        multiCastSequence(sequenceOrderingQueue.get(shouldIMultiCastMessage));
                        avd2LocalClock++;
                        sequenceOrderingQueue.remove(shouldIMultiCastMessage);
                        orderingQueueCheck(2);
                        break;
                    }                       
                }
            }
        }

        private void multiCastSequence(String string) 
        {               
            globalClock++;
            String seqMessage="sequenceMessage"+","+string+","+globalClock;
            multiCastMessage(seqMessage);

        }

        private void checkSQ(int lc) 
        {
            if(sequenceQueue.containsValue(lc))
            {
                Set<Long> keys= sequenceQueue.keySet();
                Iterator<Long> it=keys.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext())
                {
                    Long l=(Long)it.next();
                    if(sequenceQueue.get(l)==lc)
                    {
                        String upMesg=holdbackQueue.get(l);
                        new displayMessage().execute(upMesg);
                        localClock++;
                        holdbackQueue.remove(l);
                        sequenceQueue.remove(l);
                        checkSQ(localClock+1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
class displayMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        return params[0];
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String [] finalMessage=result.split(":");
        cv_pushToContentProvider = new ContentValues();
        cv_pushToContentProvider.put("key",globalClock);

        if(finalMessage.length > 2)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.append("\n"+finalMessage[2]);
            cv_pushToContentProvider.put("value", finalMessage[2]);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalMessage[2],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.append("\n"+result);
            cv_pushToContentProvider.put("value", result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mContentResolver.insert(mUri, cv_pushToContentProvider);
    }       
}
public void sendMessage(View v)
{
    String send_ClientMessage;
    EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    send_ClientMessage=ed.getText().toString();
    if(send_ClientMessage == null || send_ClientMessage == "")
        return;
    String sender=null;
    if(emulator_instance == 5554)
    {
        long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
        sender="avd0"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+":"+send_ClientMessage+","+random_key;
        sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
    }
    else if(emulator_instance == 5556)
    {
        long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
        sender="avd1"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+":"+send_ClientMessage+","+random_key;
        sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
    }
    else if(emulator_instance == 5558)
    {
        long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
        sender="avd2"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+":"+send_ClientMessage+","+random_key;
        sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
    }
    multiCastMessage(sender);
    ed.setText(null);
}
public void testOne(View v)
{
    //System.out.println("In test One");
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                //System.out.println("Sending Message");
                long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
                String s=null;

                if(emulator_instance == 5554)
                {
                    s="avd0"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key;
                    sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
                }
                else if(emulator_instance == 5556)
                {
                    s="avd1"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key;
                    sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
                }
                else if(emulator_instance == 5558)
                {
                    s="avd2"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key;
                    sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
                }
                multiCastMessage(s);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
public void testTwo(View v)
{
    test2=true;

    String s=null;
    if(emulator_instance == 5554)
    {
        long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
        s="avd0"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key+","+"test2"+","+"pass";;
        sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
    }
    else if(emulator_instance == 5556)
    {
        long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
        s="avd1"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key+","+"test2"+","+"pass";;
        sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
    }
    else if(emulator_instance == 5558)
    {
        long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
        s="avd2"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key+","+"test2"+","+"pass";;
        sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
    }
    multiCastMessage(s);
}
private void testCaseMultiCastMessage()
{
    for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
    {
        long random_key = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
        String s1=null;
        if(emulator_instance == 5554)
        {
            s1="avd0"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key;
            sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
        }
        else if(emulator_instance == 5556)
        {
            s1="avd1"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key;
            sequenceNumberLocalApp++;

        }
        else if(emulator_instance == 5558)
        {
            s1="avd2"+":"+sequenceNumberLocalApp+","+random_key;
            sequenceNumberLocalApp++;
        }

        multiCastMessage(s1);
    }
}
private void multiCastMessage(final String message) 
{
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Socket s=null;
        try {
            s=new Socket(localHost,11112);
            sendandUpdate(s,message);
            s.close();
            s=null;
            s=new Socket(localHost,11116);
            sendandUpdate(s,message);
            s.close();
            s=null;
            s=new Socket(localHost,11108);
            sendandUpdate(s,message);
            s.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}).start(); 

}
private void sendandUpdate(Socket s, String message) throws IOException 
{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.println(message);
    pw.close();
    s.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace from LogCat? And highlight the row in your code that it points to?

Comment: post your logcat for your errors and trace your code line by line to find out which line throws NPE

Comment: read the logcat. Where you readed NullPointerException you will read the line too.